# How to write terraform plan to a tab in azure devops pipeline summary?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, task, pipeline, show

Some Terraform extensions like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform) are providing a feature to publish Terraform plan to a tab in the pipeline run overview/summary.

[Terraform task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks) published by Microsoft DevLabs is not currently supporting this feature.

I'm trying to make use of the pipeline logging command [uploadsummary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#uploadsummary-add-some-markdown-content-to-the-build-summary) as a workaround for this.

```
  # Write terraform show output in default format to a markdown file
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    name: TerraformShow
    displayName: Terraform Show
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: $(sctfbackend)
      command: 'show'
      commandOptions: 'tfplan -no-color'
      outputTo: 'file'
      outputFormat: 'default'
      fileName: '$(working_dir)/TerraformPlan.md'
      workingDirectory: $(working_dir)

  # Display plan in the pipeline build summary
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Show plan summary
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      workingDirectory: '$(working_dir)'
      script: |
        echo "##vso[task.uploadsummary]$(working_dir)/TerraformPlan.md"
```

But it reads the input file as Markdown. So the formatting of the output looks ugly in the tab. The `#` in the plan output will be taken as heading1 in Markdown. `+` will be taken as bullets for list...etc as shown below:

[image]

How can I fix this to get a cleaner Terraform plan tab in the pipeline summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround.

This snippet can be used in the pipeline to achieve the same.

````
  # NOTE: Some lines in the output were missing while using this task.
  # Write terraform show output in default format to a markdown file
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    name: TerraformShow
    displayName: Terraform Show
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: $(sctfbackend)
      command: 'show'
      commandOptions: 'tfplan -no-color'
      outputTo: 'file'
      outputFormat: 'default'
      fileName: '$(working_dir)/TerraformPlan.md'
      workingDirectory: $(working_dir)

  # Display plan in the pipeline build summary
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Show plan summary
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      workingDirectory: '$(working_dir)'
      script: |
        ls -la
        sed -i '1 i\```' TerraformPlan.md
        echo '```' >> TerraformPlan.md
        echo "##vso[task.uploadsummary]$(working_dir)/TerraformPlan.md"
````

The first step is to get the plan file using `-out`. Then show the plan
with the flag `-no-color` to avoid the coloring characters in the output.

Write it to a markdown file.

Enclosing the content of that file in a **code block** of markdown will provide much cleaner formatting.

Then publish the file to the pipeline summary.

[image]